# How to get the front part of some words in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to get the front part of some words in a sentence.
For example the sentence is -

```
x <- c("Ace Bayou Reannounces Recall of Bean Bag Chairs Due to Low Rate of Consumer Response; Two Child Deaths Previously Reported; Consumers Urged to Install Repair", "Panasonic Recalls Metal Cutter Saws Due to Laceration Hazard")
```

Now I want get the front part of Recall or Recalls. I have tried various functions from R like grep, grepl, pmatch , str_split. However, I could not get exactly what I want .

what I need is only

```
"Ace Bayou Reannounces"
"Panasonic"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just `sapply(strsplit(x, 'Recall'), '[', 1)` will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use regular expressions.

```
gsub(pattern = "(.*(?=Recall(s*)))(.*)", replacement = "\\1", x = x, perl = T)
```

Comment: if `x=("Children's Jewelry Recalled by SmileMakers Due to High Levels of Cadmium","Ace Bayou Reannounces Recall of Bean Bag Chairs Due to Low Rate of Consumer Response; Two Child Deaths Previously Reported; Consumers Urged to Install Repair", "Panasonic Recalls Metal Cutter Saws Due to Laceration Hazard")`, I want get the front part of Recall or Recalls, or behind the "Recalled by". What I need is
`"SmileMakers"
"Ace Bayou Reannounces"
"Panasonic"`